# wkhtmltopdf: Page breaks and multi column layouts doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using `wkhtmltopdf`(11.0_rc1) via `wicked_pdf` gem. I am noticing that the multi column layouts doesn't play well with page breaks.

I also noticed the behavior varies between CentOS(on  Heroku) and Windows. On Windows, page break is honored in some cases.

Have you encountered such issues before? Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type='text/css'>
      .page {
        page-break-after:always !important;
        clear:both;
        display:block;
      }

      #content {
        width: 800px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div class="page">
        <div style="float:left;width:200px;">
          DESCRIPTION 1
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
          PIE CHART IMAGE 1
        </div>        
      </div>

      <div class="page">
        <div style="float:left;width:200px;">
          DESCRIPTION 2
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
          PIE CHART IMAGE 2
        </div>        
      </div>

      <div class="page">
        <div style="float:left;width:200px;">
          DESCRIPTION 3
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
          PIE CHART IMAGE 3
        </div>        
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the answer and article detailed here:

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/96

It is likely the version of wkhtmltopdf you have installed was not patched with QT.

Answer (score 0):

you can see how to install [patched version of QT](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html)

its worked for me. and keep your html as simple as possible.

Comment: Link and any of its corresponding work do not affect page breaks. I'm using QT 4.8.4 wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 wicked_pdf 0.9.4